# php 7zip windows command line not working

Tags: php, windows, command-line

In one of my program i need to zip and password protect a file using php. In php ,zip ,password protection only support in 5.6. I am un able to upgrade my php version due to some technical reason. So i download a 7zip software in my windows system and zip through command line.

this is two command

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip

7z a D:\test.zip d:/xampp/testdata -ptest
```

This working perfectly in my command prompt. This is not working when i done with php

This is my code.

```
  $enviornment = "set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip";
  exec($enviornment , $output, $return);
  $cmd = "7z a D:\test.zip d:/xampp/testdata -ptest";
  exec($cmd , $output, $return);
```

This both are return 0 as result.

Answer (score 0):

A return code of "0" means the program exited normally **without** an error.

Just as an information:

[Here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html) is a list of common non-zero (error) return codes.

PS: Be careful with backslashes (\) in Strings. In the middle of a String you can use single "\" but at the end you have to use double "\\"

```
$str = "ABC\DEF"; //OK
$str2 = "ABCDEF\\"; //OK
```